# Unix: How to group every two columns?

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file like:
`id1 A B C T G A B C 
 id2 G V L P A J M T`

and I would like to have:
`id1 AB CT GA BC 
 id2 GV LP AJ MT`

Any suggestion?

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45577119/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins - it will teach you how to do what you want using awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\([A-Z]\) \([A-Z]\)/\1\2/g' file
```

---

Or ***awk*** alternative:

```
awk '{ r=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) r=r FS $i$(i+1); print r }' file
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
id1 AB CT GA BC 
id2 GV LP AJ MT
```

Answer (score 2):

another `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/ \1\2/g' file

id1 AB CT GA BC
id2 GV LP AJ MT
```

works even if your id field has the same char set.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -np -e 's/ ([A-Z]) ([A-Z])/ $1$2/g' <FILENAME
```

Replace FILENAME with the name of the input file.

Comment: When I think about it, the capital letters in your example are probably placeholders anything separated by space.  If that is true, replace "[A-Z]" with "[^ \t]" (anything but space or tab characters).  Using \s, \w, \d etc. is problematic.  The notion of "space", "word characters", "digits" is locale dependent.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf (i%2)?$i" ":$i}printf RS}' file
```

If the number of the field is odd, print `$i" "`, else print `$i`